# OpenEdge\Progress to SQL Server Export

Tags: sql-server, openedge, progress-db

I come mainly from mysql\apache background but we have a group project with a few other sister company and converting all our databases into one reporting server.

Our main systems that are used by sales\staff are built on Progress OpenEdge and I am trying to create export files of these DBS\Tables into output files that can be fed into the sql server using the software available from SQL Server.

The person at the OpenEdge\Progress side of things is AFK most of the day (and very protective over it i.e. i cant poke around the system) and from what I see uses something called SQLExplorer (JDBC) to translate any SQL against this database.

This process will happily output a text file using a very basic SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM QUERY.PUB.case_process
```

but it has no delimiter so cant be fed into the sql server

I have provided the following which executes fine on the SSMS and has delimiters etc.

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT * FROM QUERY.PUB.case_process" queryout c:\case_process_cmdshell_test.txt -t"|" -c -T '
```

but it is throwing back an error when tried against OpenEdge

```
SQLState=HY000
ErrorCode=-210056
[DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Syntax error in SQL statement at or about "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SEL" (10713)
```

I have tried to make sure that there are no SQL-92 reserved words and few other small things

I'm actually at a loss as the MySQL DBs I have locally which I am sending data to this SQL server just involved ODBC\SSMA and works like a dream but I'm being told there is not an equivalent for OpenEdge\Progress

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't have a delimiter"? Is it a fixed-width file? BCP *can* read such files with a format file. In any case, one part of your issue is that you are trying to use a SQl Server specific procedure like `xp_cmdshell` in a completely unrelated product.

Comment: Even if you tried to run this command in SQL Server it would be a bad idea You are trying to run an external program like `bcp` from inside the database itself.  There is no reason to do that *at all*, althouth there are a lot of reasons to avoid it, including the need for elevated priviledges. Just run bcp from the command line

Comment: In any case, you *can* use bcp to load fixed-width files generated from Postgres, [as shown here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129(v=sql.110).aspx).  A *better* option perhaps would be to install the Postgres OLEDB driver, configure the other server as [a Linked server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3662/sql-server-and-postgresql-linked-server-configuration--part-2/) and execute queries against it from SQL Server itself

Comment: Progress <> postgres

Comment: The Progress sqlexp output is in a fixed length format.

Comment: i would prefer the idea suggested by Pantagiotis but that will be not something

I have checked the files generated by Postgres and yes (sorry) they are fixed-width files.

I thought of a delimited type of output as the difference in size for that particular table between the one that is created using the xp_cmdshell (i know bad idea i.e. security) or a delimited text file using SSMS -> query -> export to file comes out at 158meg compared to the Postgres fixed-width file is 2.1 gig thus making it a nightmare to inspect